# Simple JS CSS change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I got a header div, which I'd like to expand smoothly to height:300px onClick.
I'm a total noob in JS, none of the various tutorials wasn't good for me.
See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9UzNq/).

HTML:

```
   <div style="position:absolute; font-family:century gothic; width:100%; top: 45px;        font-size: 20px; margin:0px; height:130px; margin-top:0px; text-align:center; ">
<div style="background:white; width:100%; z-index:2; border-bottom: 1px solid gray; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px; position:fixed; height: 70px; top:0px;">
<img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/10qanv9.gif" onmouseover="this.src='http://i43.tinypic.com/28150s3.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i43.tinypic.com/10qanv9.gif'" height="70px" style="margin-top:0px;">
</div>
    <!--When clicked, expand this div to 'height:300px', the logo should stay as the one glowing one.-->
```

Comment: If you want something to expand smoothly, you're going to have to use CSS3 or a javascript animation library (like jQuery or other). I would also not use inline styles and javascript, and start using stylesheets and `<script>` tags.

Comment: If you don't understand JavaScript and don't want to spend more effort in learning it, try using CSS3 transitions as MattDiamant suggested.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige I already know CSS3 transitions quite well, but the best I can do with it is an animation on hover, but as I'm wanting it to expand on click, CSS3 is pretty much no use.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige I'm planning on learning JS, but now I just needed this solution quick.

Comment: Overead the click, sorry. If you're familiar with css3 transitions, I would recommend to use jquery to add and possibly remove a class via $('#toggler').click() or $('#toggler').toggle()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you're missing a closing `</div>` tag

To animate the height, tag the `div` with an `id` such as `<div id = "myDiv">` then import and use jQuery like so:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({height: "300px"}, 1000); 
});
```

The second argument is the animation time in ms.

For noob lessons on JavaScript and jQuery, I recommend www.codeacademy.com

Comment: I'm planning on learning it, but now I just needed this solution quick.